# jQuery: Introducir retraso en la ejecución de un bucle

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

He creado un script jQuery para, desde mi página web, automatizar la creación de listas en mi canal de YouTube. El problema es que la API no parece ser capaz de atender las quince peticiones de adición de vídeos que hago por lista a través de un `each()`; añade entre cuatro y seis, y muchas veces no en el orden que debería, así que he pensado que una posible solución sería añadir un retraso al final de cada ciclo del bucle para que el servidor tenga tiempo de reaccionar a cada petición.

El script:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.crear-lista-yt').click(function() //Al hacer clic en el botón "Publicar"
    {
        var idLista = $(this).parent().siblings('.bloque-canciones').attr('id'); //Captura el id de la lista
        var nombre = $(this).parent().siblings('.nombre-lista').html(); //Captura el nombre de la lista
        var descripcion = $(this).parent().siblings('.descripcion-lista').html(); //Captura la descripción de la lista
        
        var idListaYT; //Variable para almacenar posteriormente el enlace de la lista de YouTube creada

        var peticionLista = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert( //Se almacenan en la variable los datos (título, descripción y estado) que definen la lista a crear
        {
            part: 'snippet, status',
            resource: 
            {
                snippet: 
                {
                    title: nombre,
                    description: descripcion
                },
                status: {privacyStatus: 'public'}
            }
        });

        peticionLista.execute(function(respuesta) //Se ejecuta la petición
        {
            idListaYT = respuesta.result.id; //Se almacena el id de la lista creada

            if(idListaYT) //Si se ha creado la lista
            {
                $(`.cancion-lista-${idLista}`).each(function() //Bucle que recorre todas las canciones del recopilatorio personalizado
                {
                    var idVideoYT = $(this).children().children('.enlace-youtube').data('video'); //Id de YoutTube correspondiente a cada cancion

                    var detalles = {videoId: idVideoYT, kind: 'youtube#video'} //Se almacena el id del vídeo y que es un vídeo de YouTube

                    var peticionCancion = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert( //De manera similar a como se hace con la lista, en esta variable se almacenan los datos de cada vídeo
                    {
                        part: 'snippet',
                        resource: 
                        {
                            snippet: 
                            {
                                playlistId: idListaYT, //El id de la lista a la que se añade el vídeo
                                resourceId: detalles //Los datos de cada vídeo
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    peticionCancion.execute(function(respuesta) //Se ejecuta la petición
                    {
                        if(respuesta.result)
                        {
                            console.log(respuesta.result.snippet.title);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log('No se ha agregado el vídeo')
                        }
                    });

                    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Han pasado 1000 ms'); }, 1000);
                });
            }
            else swal('Ups...', 'Algo ha fallado; intenta crear tu lista de YouTube más tarde...', 'error', {button: false}); //Si no, da un mensaje de error
        });
    });
});
```

Bueno, huelga decir que `setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Han pasado 1000 ms'); }, 1000)` no me está funcionando; un ejemplo de lo que muestra la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta ocasión ha sido capaz de añadir sólo cinco de los quince vídeos -aquellos para los que se hace `console.log(respuesta.result.snippet.title);`- y mis intentos de retraso aparecen todos al final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente el proceso no ha durado al menos 15.000 ms, la información ha aparecido de inmediato en la consola.

¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Puedes usar promesas o funciones async, te recomiendo mas la ultima

Comment: ¿Puedes detallar un poco más tu sugerencia? Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: lo que sucede es que js no es como otros lenguajes que se ejecuta en bloque, el hoisting puede ejecutar parte de tu código en distintos lados al tiempo, con promesas o async lo que haces es decirle a js que no siga ejecutando código hasta que termine cierta acción, te recomiendo usar async, es mas fácil

Comment: He encontrado un artículo bastante detallado sobre el tema, por si alguien le interesa: https://lemoncode.net/lemoncode-blog/2018/1/29/javascript-asincrono

Comment: Creo haber entendido del artículo que estos métodos asíncronos son para evitar que el flujo se detenga y no sea necesario esperar a que un paso se resuelva para abordar el siguiente, pero a mí no me interesa que las canciones se añadan a la lista cuando sea posible, sino en el orden que el usuario haya establecido en mi página web. Si una canción ha de ir en la tercera posición de la lista, quiero que aparezca tercera, y no quinta porque el servidor pudo añadir antes las dos siguientes.

Comment: Tu error esta en el each, debes probar un arrow function con async, el bloque se sigue ejecutando así el api responda con un 500, debes esperar a que se ejecute el llamado, en cuanto al orden pues eres tu o el usuario el que lo define, creo que recorrer los elementos de la clase no es optimo, porque no pruebas haciendo una estructura como un array y luego solo recorres

Comment: ¿Pasar los quince elementos a un array y luego recorrer ese array?

Comment: Es que realmente no se entiende como esta tu algoritmo o que quieres hacer, por lo que veo el usuario escoge las canciones y tu recorres las que el haya seleccionado mediante jquery, despues haces un loop y vas enviado a su playlist de youtube, es algo así?

Comment: Sí, el usuario elige 15 canciones en mi web, en un determinado orden, y cuando está conforme le da al botón "Publicar" y el script crea la lista de YouTube y le añade las canciones mediante el bucle.

Comment: Ahhh ok, claro amigo, tu no estas dando el orden, yo haría como te dije, asigno un evento a la clase con jquery o js vanilla y voy haciendo un push a un array, luego lo recorro y pues para que el usuario sepa en qur orden van le coloco un div con la.info

Comment: Tengo ententido que este tipo de automatizaciones estan restringidas. Para evitarlas basta con que el usuario toque la pantalla con el mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diría que el problema es que estás lanzando demasiadas peticiones en paralelo, y dado que quieres que queden en el orden que tienes definido, quizás lo mejor sea serializar las peticiones, es decir, que vaya una hasta que se haya completado la anterior.

Para lograrlo sin tener que cambiar toda la lógica de tu script, puedes hacer un arreglo con las peticiones a ejecutar y lanzar la siguiente petición, si la hay, hasta que termine la primera.

Para ello, haría falta factorizar el código de la función que se ejecuta al completar cada petición en una función independiente, digamos `alFinalizarPeticion`. Esta función, además de imprimir los mensajes, será la responsable de lanzar la siguiente petición. La rutina que lanza la siguiente petición, a su vez, entrega la referencia a `alFinalizarPeticion` para ser invocada cuando termine y así repetir la operación hasta que terminen todas las peticiones, por ejemplo por este código:

```
let peticionesPendientes = [];

function ejecutarSiguientePeticion() {
  if (peticionesPendientes.length > 0) {
    let siguientePeticion = peticionesPendientes.shift();
    siguientePeticion.execute(alFinalizarPeticion);
  }
}

function alFinalizarPeticion(respuesta) {
  if(respuesta.result) {
    console.log(respuesta.result.snippet.title);
  } else {
    console.log('No se ha agregado el vídeo')
  }
  ejecutarSiguientePeticion();
}
```

Ahora, entonces, habría que ajustar el código original para que vaya colocando las peticiones en el arreglo y, al final, lance la primera petición, algo como:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.crear-lista-yt').click(function() //Al hacer clic en el botón "Publicar"
    {
        var idLista = $(this).parent().siblings('.bloque-canciones').attr('id'); //Captura el id de la lista
        var nombre = $(this).parent().siblings('.nombre-lista').html(); //Captura el nombre de la lista
        var descripcion = $(this).parent().siblings('.descripcion-lista').html(); //Captura la descripción de la lista
        
        var idListaYT; //Variable para almacenar posteriormente el enlace de la lista de YouTube creada

        var peticionLista = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert( //Se almacenan en la variable los datos (título, descripción y estado) que definen la lista a crear
        {
            part: 'snippet, status',
            resource: 
            {
                snippet: 
                {
                    title: nombre,
                    description: descripcion
                },
                status: {privacyStatus: 'public'}
            }
        });

        peticionLista.execute(function(respuesta) //Se ejecuta la petición
        {
            idListaYT = respuesta.result.id; //Se almacena el id de la lista creada

            if(idListaYT) //Si se ha creado la lista
            {
                $(`.cancion-lista-${idLista}`).each(function() //Bucle que recorre todas las canciones del recopilatorio personalizado
                {
                    var idVideoYT = $(this).children().children('.enlace-youtube').data('video'); //Id de YoutTube correspondiente a cada cancion

                    var detalles = {videoId: idVideoYT, kind: 'youtube#video'} //Se almacena el id del vídeo y que es un vídeo de YouTube

                    var peticionCancion = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert( //De manera similar a como se hace con la lista, en esta variable se almacenan los datos de cada vídeo
                    {
                        part: 'snippet',
                        resource: 
                        {
                            snippet: 
                            {
                                playlistId: idListaYT, //El id de la lista a la que se añade el vídeo
                                resourceId: detalles //Los datos de cada vídeo
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    peticionesPendientes.push(peticionCancion);

                });
                ejecutarSiguientePeticion();
            }
            else swal('Ups...', 'Algo ha fallado; intenta crear tu lista de YouTube más tarde...', 'error', {button: false}); //Si no, da un mensaje de error
        });
    });
});
```

Si aún quieres arriesgarte a enviar varias peticiones en paralelo, y solo *espaciarlas* en el tiempo, puedes utilizar una infraestructura similar, solo que en lugar de lanzar la siguiente hasta que termine una petición, lanzarla con un timer. Entonces, re-escribiendo la primera parte:

```
let timerEjecucion;

function ejecutarSiguientePeticion() {
  if (peticionesPendientes.length > 0) {
    let siguientePeticion = peticionesPendientes.shift();
    siguientePeticion.execute(alFinalizarPeticion);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerEjecucion);
  }
}

function alFinalizarPeticion(respuesta) {
  if(respuesta.result) {
    console.log(respuesta.result.snippet.title);
  } else {
    console.log('No se ha agregado el vídeo')
  }
}
```

Para iniciar las ejecuciones, entonces, habría que establecer el timer. Estoy usando un timer tipo intervalo para que se ejecute de manera automática varias veces, hasta que complete la tarea. Para iniciar la *cadena*, habría que llamar a `setInterval()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
  timerEjecucion = setInterval(ejecutarSiguientePeticion, 1000);
  ejecutarSiguientePeticion();
```

He colocado una llamada a `ejecutarSiguientePeticion()` justo después de `setInterval()` para no esperar un segundo antes de que se lance la primera petición. Se podría eliminar esta línea si la espera es necesaria o aceptable.

Esto lanzará una petición cada segundo hasta completar las que estén en el arreglo.

OJO: El código podría contener errores de sintaxis, lo he escrito aquí mismo y, dado que no publicas un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no tengo fácil ponerlo a prueba. Espero que, si entiendes la solución con la explicación que te he dado, seas capaz de corregir cualquier detalle que se me haya podido escapar.

Comment: La primera solución funciona perfectamente, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

No tengo puntaje para dejar un comentario, pero espero ser de utilidad.

En la mayoría de las apis de google que yo he podido usar, primero se hacen todas las operaciones de inserción y al final se ejecutan todas juntas.
Por lo que pude entender de tu codigo, vos estas insertando, ejecutando, en ciclo.

intenta hacer el ciclo únicamente de las inserciones y finalmente hace la ejecución.

Si mi respuesta no es acertada, déjamelo saber asi la borro, saludos.

Comment: Ahora ya tenés reputación para comentar, pero esto es una buena respuesta, no iría como comentario. No es necesario que una publicación tenga código para responder a una pregunta.